# Problems binding a windows forms datetimepicker to an entity framework object

Tags: vb.net, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding, datetimepicker

I'm currently trying to load data from an Oracle 11g database table into my VB.Net application and display it in a Windows Forms.

Within that form, I have a `TextBox` and a `DateTimePicker`.
The form has an object called Fall, which in turn contains an entity framework representation of my database table b_stc_fall.

I bound the textbox like this:

```
txtTopic.DataBindings.Add(txtTopic.Text, Fall.B_STC_FALL, FALL.B_STC_FALL.TOPIC)
```

This works as planed.

Now I try to bind the datetimepicker:

```
DTPStartDate.DataBindings.Add(DTPStartDate.Value, Fall.B_STC_FALL, Fall.B_STC_FALL.STARTDATE)
```

`B_STC_FALL.Startdate` is a date with the value `#7/20/2014 4:47:00 PM#`

This compiles without problem, but if I run the program, the following `ArgumentException` (original message is german, I hope the translation is somewhat accurate) is thrown:

```
The property 01.08.2014 10:13:24 für the target control can not be bound
```

`01.08.2014`... is the german format for the date `#8/1/2014 10:13:24 AM#`, which is contained within `DTSStartDate.Value`

Can you give me a hint on why this won't bind?

Comment: The first parameter of `DataBindings.Add` should be the name of the property you want to bind, so "Value" seems a better candidate: `DTPStartDate.DataBindings.Add("Value", Fall.B_STC_FALL, Fall.B_STC_FALL.STARTDATE)`...